# Coding on VS code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Hello this is my first time to learn C by a book
But The code doesn't give output
I installed build essential
What should I do ?

```
int main()
{
printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: `int main` not `intmain`

Comment: @steeldriver same problem

Comment: You may want to take this to Stack Overflow …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code that you are trying to compile, that is at `line 3`:

`intmain` which needs to be replaced by `int main`
Also Add `return 0;` at the list line inside main function to prevent your application return some  unwanted output

Full Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```